# Python: listing IP ranges

Tags: python

I have problem with the netaddr package - version 0.7.5. This code works as expected and prints out the list of ip addresses in the range:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

ipnetwork = '192.168.0.0/24'
print list(IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts())
```

However, if I change the network to, say, '192.168.0.0/8' my script just hangs:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

ipnetwork = '192.168.0.0/8'
print list(IPNetwork(ipnetwork).iter_hosts())
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

Looks like I was missing something by not realising how big that range is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not just taking a lot of time? You are making a list out of the iterator. When I run that on my machine, I get 100% CPU usage and memory usage increase. I can also print out the entire range if I use the iterator directly.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I've just done that. I didn't realise the range was so big.

Comment: @normski Yup, 2**24 elements, totally nothing special =)